# REST support within a java templating engine such as StringTemplate, FreeMarker, Velocity or Tiles?

Tags: velocity, freemarker, stringtemplate, apache-tiles, templating-engine

I'd like to compare some templating engines that supports creating RESTful URLS for templating header/body/footer pages in a java application.  I don't want my pages to have a jsp, .st or .ftl extension.  Does anyone have links to example applications that illustrate how to set up REST with any of the popular templating engines?

Thanks.

-John

Comment: Template engines have nothing to do with page urls. You need to be comaring frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with any of the mentioned engines. They only provide the MVC View. The visited URL belongs to the MVC Controller (the "action"). Thus, the page URL should never contain the template file name. (In JSP Model-2 frameworks you forward the HTTP request to the view page, so in that sense the templates have an URL. But this request forwarding is entirely server side, so the template URL is still not visible on the client side.) If the MVC Controllers are JSP pages, you can still hide the .jps extension by creating a catch-all central controller servlet (or filter) that adds the .jsp extension to the URL and forwards the HTTP request internally.